# Redux - Remove object from store on http response error

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, redux

**Consider the following flow:**

I have a page with a list of "products" and a modal to create a single "product". I open the modal, fill the form and submit the form.

At this point, I dispatch an action CREATING_PRODUCT, add the product to the store and send the http request to the server.

I close the modal and display the list of results with the new product.

Let's suppose I receive an error response from the server.

**Desired behavior:**

I would like to display an error, remove the project from the list, re-open the modal and display the form already filled.

**Question**

How can I find that project and remove it the list? I don't have an id (or a combination of unique properties) to find that project in the store. I don't see a clean way to link a request/response to that "product" object in the store.

**Possible solution**

The client adds a "requestId" into the project before adding it to the store. On response error, I dispatch a generic "CREATE_ERROR" and I remove the project with that requestId from the store.

**Extra**

Same problem with edit and delete. For example during a delete should I keep a reference to the deleted project with the requestId in the store, until the http request is successful?

I bet it is a problem with a common solution, but I can't find examples.
Thanks!

Comment: Why not wait until you have a successful response before storing it at all?

Comment: As redux enforces you to take an immutable approach. I recommend you to have a temporary id to keep track of the objects. But, can't you wait for the success response to add it to the list ?

Comment: You could also implement `redux-undo`. So, if an error occur, you undo the action

Comment: But undoing an action could result in undoing actions that happened between the request and the error result.

Comment: @PeterLaBanca Yeah, that could be a way to avoid the problem, but I like the idea of a snappy interface without showing a loader. I am still evaluating if the complexity is worth the investment.

Comment: @JoãoMosmann I took a quick look to redux-undo. Interesting, but you are right: an undo would revert other changes on that slice of the store that could have happened in the meanwhile and maybe are totally unrelated.

Comment: @oriodesign dealing with temporary ids is going to increase the complexity(I did this and hated it very much because of additional management that comes with it), Instead introduce a component state for creating a project and do not dispatch 'CREATING_PRODUCT' until you receive the response from API, this way you don't have to worry about removing the added product from the store If there is an error in API response. You will dispatch only when the response is success. You can show component's state data in the create-product modal. Hope this works for you. I found this easy tbh.

Answer (score 1):

In general, your Redux store should be modeled somewhat like a relational database, in that every time you have a list of data models, each element of the list should have its own identifier. This helps a lot when dealing with more complex data schemes.

You should probably store your projects as an object, something like:

```
{ 
  // ...other store properties
  projects: {
    "_0": { // ... project properties }
    "_1": { // ... project properties }
    // ...more projects...
  },
}
```

This way, whenever you need to mess with an existing project, you can just reference its id and use `projects[id]` to access that project. This would also solve the edit and delete cases, as you could just pass the IDs around as handles.

I like [this short piece](https://medium.com/@adamrackis/querying-a-redux-store-37db8c7f3b0f) on why your Redux store should be mostly flat and why data should always have identifiers very much. It also talks about using selectors to "hide" your IDs away, which may or may not be useful for you.

In your case, as you are getting IDs from a server, you could have an ID prefix which indicates unsaved values. So your `projects` object would become something like:

```
projects: {
  "_0": { // ... }
  "_1": { // ... }
  "UNSAVED_2": { // ... }
}
```

This way, you could easily identify unsaved values and handle them when an error occurs, still get the benefits of generating temp IDs on the client-side in order to revert changes on error, and also warn your user if they try to leave your app while their data still hasn't been synchronized - just check if there are any "UNSAVED" IDs :)

When you get a response from the server, you could change the "UNSAVED_suffix" ID to an actual ID.

Comment: I am implementing it with this approach, but the "id" comes from the server and before receiving the response that id is still null. If instead, you are talking of an id generated by the client, then I assume it is not exchanged with the server and still on response error body I don't have that id to find the correct and remove it from the store.

Comment: Instead of using `null`, you could reserve an ID string prefix which indicates that this property is not saved server-side. That way, when you get a server error, you could just keep working and try synchronizing again later, and warn the user their data is not synchronized yet if they try closing the app.

Comment: Good idea and thanks for the link. Two problems: 1) I have to be careful not to use this temporary id to make any extra request to the server until it is not updated. 2) For edit and delete, the id is already set and this approach forces me to change a correct server generated id adding a prefix.

Maybe I having a { _request: "pending" } property inside the product would help to solve the issue. So I base my decision on that property and not the id.

Comment: Well, yes. You'll have to add some extra logic to check for temporary IDs, but that can be solved by writing a `isTemporaryId` predicate. As for problem 2, you should change any ID to a temp ID whenever you're doing work that needs to be synchronized. You could set it back to the previous ID as soon as the server confirms synchronization.

Comment: Thanks Pedro, very helpful.

Comment: Glad to have helped!